# The movie game - skipping "The" at the beginning of a movie

Tags: python

The Movie Game is a game played by two people, and goes as follows. The first player names a movie. The second player then names a new movie whose title starts with the last letter of the movie the first player named.

The game we will ignore the definite article "the" So if a player names the movie "Her Alibi" the next player can name the movie "The Incredibles," since the article "the" is ignored.

How can I remove "The" from the movie title?

```
def userInput(lastInput):
    if lastInput == None:
            return str(input("Enter a movie title: ")).lower()
    if lastInput[:4] == "The ": # doesn't work
        lastInput = lastInput[4:] # doesn't work
    while True:
        userChoice = str(input("Enter a movie title: ")).lower()
        if userChoice[0] == lastInput[-1]:
            return userChoice
        else:
            print("\nInvalid input, what would you like to do?")
            instructions()
```

Comment: `userChoice = userChoice[4:] if userChoice.startswith('the ') else userChoice`

Comment: If the first movie is `Her Alibi` and you go through the code then when it asks for another input it wouldn't work because `The Incredibles` is being passed in at the line where you are asking for `userChoice`.  You are running the check for the word `The` in the wrong part of the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the Part of the string In The case You Mentioned **THE** with an empty string ,
use 
The following Code to Remove the word You want from the string

```
str="The Incredibles"
str.replace("The","")
```

Comment: Not a solid solution, as `The` could appear anywhere in the string. I.e., '**The**ir Troubles', 'Trial of **the** Kings', etc.

Comment: ohk yes I Did not considered that !! will get back with a solution

Answer (score 0):

Consider using regular expressions

```
import re
a = r'^(\bthe\b)'
sts  = ['the incredibles', 'theodore', 'at the mueseum', 'their words' ]
for i in sts:
    b = re.sub(a,'', i)
    print(b)
```

The regular expression I am using seems to work, but you might want to test more examples, using this link https://regex101.com/r/pX5sD5/3

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
if lastInput.lower().startswith("the "): lastInput = lastInput[4:]
```

Using the `startswith()` method of strings, you can test for the first word directly (including the space that follows it).  In order to support various capitalisation, turning the string to lowercase (using `lower()`) allows you to only perform one test for any combinations of upper/lower case variants (e.g. "The ", "the ", "THE ").

I also noticed that you are not applying this exclusion logic to the userChoice variable which is where I would have expected this to be used rather than on the lastInput variable.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.